# Calculating a query with accumulation of the previous result in postgresql

Tags: excel, postgresql, report, window-functions

I need to run a calculation that must take in account his previous result and have a starting balance.

The formula is PREVIOUS RESULT or INITIAL IF FIRST - profit + loans. In excel this is easy:

```
1- A1=Initial
2- A2=A1 - B2:profit + C2:loans
3- A3=A2 - B3:profit + C3:loans
4- A4=A3 - B4:profit + C4:loans
```

But how do this with sql?

Comment: what inpput do you have, what result do you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL you have to use recursive query or function to get *previous result in current query*. This is rather complicated and instead of this you can use an aggregate (in this case `sum()`) called as a window function, which is also known as *cumulative aggregate*.

Example setup:

```
create table my_table(id serial primary key, val int, profit int, loans int);
insert into my_table values (val, profit, loans)
(100, null, null),
(null, 10, 20),
(null, 20, 10),
(null, 40, 30);
```

Query:

```
select 
    id, 
    sum(val) over w + sum(-coalesce(profit, 0)+ coalesce(loans, 0)) over w as val,
    profit, 
    loans
from my_table
window w as (order by id)
order by id;

 id | val | profit | loans 
----+-----+--------+-------
  1 | 100 |        |      
  2 | 110 |     10 |    20
  3 | 100 |     20 |    10
  4 |  90 |     40 |    30
(4 rows)
```